# How to create a partition in MySql if it doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a partitioned table, in which I'm inserting data from a stored procedure,
I have partitioning on the table by a column named `year`,
The stored procedure is able to insert data into the partitioned table properly.

But now I have a case where inserts might happen, for which partitions may not be present,
I need a solution to find if a particular partition name exists for the table.

Eg. My table name is `backups`
I have 3 Partitions for now -
2018, 2019 and 2020
But in the year 2021 which the stored procedure runs,
 
there may not be a partition for the year
So I wish my stored procedure handle the checking and creation of the partition at run time.

**Following is my table structure -**

[image]

**Partition creation query -**

```
ALTER TABLE backups
partition by list columns(year)
(partition backup_2018 values IN (2018),
partition backup_2019 values IN (2019),
partition backup_2020 values IN (2020));
```

**Following is my stored procedure -**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `daily_backup`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE backuptime INT;

    #Need Partition checking and creation here

    SET backuptime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 DAY),' 23:59:59'));

    INSERT into backups 
    (user_id, latest_transaction_id, balance, last_transaction_timestamp, last_transaction_date, snapshot_date, year)    
    SELECT 
    T2.user_id,
    T2.transaction_id AS latest_transaction_id,
    T2.new_balance AS balance,
    T2.created_date AS last_transaction_timestamp,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.created_date), '%Y-%m-%d %I:%i:%S') AS last_transaction_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') AS snapshot_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') AS year
FROM
    (SELECT 
        user_id, MAX(transaction_id) maxTransID
    FROM
        transaction
    WHERE
        created_date < @backuptime
    GROUP BY user_id) Tmp
        JOIN
    transaction T2 ON Tmp.MaxTransID = T2.Transaction_ID;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest partitioning using [RANGE COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html) instead of `LIST COLUMNS`. That way you have the option of adding a last column for any years beyond the partitions you have defined so far.

```
ALTER TABLE backups
partition by range columns(year)
(partition backup_2018 values LESS THAN (2019),
partition backup_2019 values LESS THAN (2020),
partition backup_2020 values LESS THAN (2021),
partition backup_other values LESS THAN MAXVALUE);
```

As you get closer to the end of 2020, you'd use `ALTER TABLE backups REORGANIZE PARTITION backup_other INTO ( ...new partitions... )` to split the last partition and make new partitions for subsequent years.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-management-range-list.html for more details.

If you forget, no harm done, your data will just fill up `backup_other` for a while until you remember to reorganize. It's to your advantage though to do it proactively, because reorganizing an empty partition is quick, and reorganizing a partition with data in it will take more time.